# How to submit a React form on <select> element change, but keep validation for other inputs in the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React form component consists of a required text `<input>` and a `<select>` elements.

I want to submit the form on every select change, but only if the required text input is filled in. However, the code below will submit the form even if the required text input is empty.

How can I prevent sumbitting the form on select change if the text input is empty? I know I can add the text input value to the component state and check it for emptiness, but then I would also need to create my own warning tooltip when the input is empty etc. (wheres the browser already provides a tooltip for required inputs).

```
const Form = () => {

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        alert('submitting')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" required />
                <select onChange={handleSubmit}>
                    <option>a</option>
                    <option>b</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: check for value's presence before submitting in handlesubmit

Comment: Thanks, but then I also need to create my own warning about the field being empty. Is there a way to keep the native browser warning for required fields?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You are not checking if input is empty or not. One of the many ways is - You can use [useref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const inputRef = useRef();

<input ref={inputRef} type="text" required />

    const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        if (inputRef.current.value) {
        alert('submitting')
        }
        else {
         alert('empty input')
        }
    }
```